# Strange error in logcat android

Tags: javascript, android, backbone.js, cordova

I'm developing an android app by phonegap,and in logcat appear this error:

```
 E/SUMAN-statusbarpolicy(1652): <!>com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.StatusBarPolicy  
 1069<!> mServiceState.getRoaming()false
```

Anyone knows this error?

Comment: Check whether you are using correct version of external plugin which should be compatible with cordova version

Comment: @Shivan Raptor, the link you provided has a question asked by himself!

Comment: Oops. Didn't aware that. Why repeat asking the same question? @Stefano

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't received reply in the last post.